# Typescript no repeat value

Tags: typescript

is there a way how to declare type array with uniq values,

i have aray of string literals and would by nice if i can say there can be only one of each string literal.

```
export type AllMapLibraries = 'drawing' | 'geometry' | 'places' | 'visualization';

export const getGoogleApiUrl = (apiKey: string, libraries: AllMapLibraries[]) => {
  const librariesString = libraries.join(',');
  const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=${librariesString}&key=${apiKey}`;
  return url;
};

const url = getGoogleApiUrl('123', ['drawing', 'geometry', 'drawing']); // here should be error that drawing was already defined;
```

it hasnt to be only array.

but i didnt find anything, and think that this is not possible.

heres the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCAbDBZAhmAGQEsAjKXKI4AZzgF44ByAE3IHciA7Ac0bgB8m3YBAC2wGFER9BjMBlwBjGjKYA3ItQCuuDEQBeuGEQidGAbgCwAKBsB6OxBgALYFDhFmqDi7jBOWqI2oJCwfgGi6Fh4hKTklDQAohFwAN5wrLgcPAA0cMJiElJ58ko0eRraugZGJpxwAL5WttYh0PCKptTwwjAA4hAQ3BjAaGBEAKpQGPRwABT4RADSwIgAXHDdlLlwemQUVNQbmDj4xPsJ1ADaALoAlPQAfGk2cHCdnN27cQc0AMqSLjcWZ7eKHAB0ACsIFw5owcow7s03h8vlpprMAAbOGAwMBHByifDUcHcQbDYCLEmdUR2In4uyLOyQ6gAfjUdAAzOCQgAyUG-ah0AAkqQFlwB224DV5AGtViLUosVogGpjkXAoBJ0fV0Rhmk0bMFwO13l0ehIBkMRmNJtNkoFZgtxiqNlsgXlwV7xYdjtEzj9Lg7RLcHnRnqlXnAbIaWqj4HrZr0rRTbVMMHCAIwAJk58LgVxY7CB+cYBXEkmkeSLWRL93McAccFcWs2zggWgwzDgJFQbig0AQziMGWLPDgbFwtF0WtwzEQGWAADMuMBmM143A9cGk5byTbxung1nc-mAAx5TN5M93IA)

Comment: Perhaps instead of an array you can declare `libraries` as a Set? I'm not sure there is a type that can emulate what the data structure does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to represent "array with no repeat elements" in the type system, your best bet will be as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type that acts as a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).  Here's how I'd start:

```
type RemoveArrayRepeats<T extends readonly any[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: (
        T[number] extends { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? never : T[P] }[number]
        ? never
        : T[K]
    )
}
```

So, the type `RemoveArrayRepeats` takes a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) type and converts it to a version of itself where any repeated elements are replaced with the `never` type.  Like this:

```
type TestSame = RemoveArrayRepeats<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]>; // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
type TestDiff = RemoveArrayRepeats<[1, 2, 3, 2, 5]>; // [1, never, 3, never, 5]
```

A sketch of how it works: given a tuple type `T`, it [maps over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) each numeric-like index `K`, and compares the union of element types of `T` (i.e., `T[number]`) with the union of element types of `T` without the element at the index `K` (i.e., `{[P in keyof T]: P extends K ? never: T[P]}[number]`.).  If they are different, great, leave this property alone.  If they are the same, we have a repeat... replace it with `never`.

As an example with `[1,2,3,2,5]`: If `K` is `"0"`, then we compare the union of elements of `[1,2,3,2,5]`, namely `1|2|3|5` with those of `[never,2,3,2,5]`, namely `2|3|5`.  Since those are different, then the first element of the tuple is not a repeat and it is left alone: `1`.  Now we look at `K` being `"1`".  We compare `1|2|3|5` with the elements of `[1,never,3,2,5]`, which is still `1|2|3|5`.  Those are the same, meaning that the second element of the tuple will be replaced with `never`.  Eventually we build up the array `[1,never,3,never,5]`.

---

Next we declare the `getGoogleApiUrl` function to be a generic function, where the `libraries` parameter is constrained to both `AllMapLibraries[]` and to `RemoveArrayRepeats<T>`:

```
declare const getGoogleApiUrl: <T extends AllMapLibraries[]>(
    apiKey: string,
    libraries: (T & RemoveArrayRepeats<T>) | []
) => string;
```

The details of how the constraint happens are a bit weird.  I chose to put `T & RemoveArrayRepeats<T>` in the parameter position so that `T` itself would only be constrained to `AllMapLibraries[]`; that keeps error messages on mistakes like `'drawink'` understandable.  But you could have instead done `T extends AllMapLibraries[] & RemoveArrayRepeats<T>` for very similar behavior.

Oh, and that `| []` in the type of `libraries` is a [trick](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990) that gives the compiler a hint that we'd like to infer a tuple type for `libraries` if possible.  Without it, the compiler sees `["drawing", "drawing", "drawing"]` as type `Array<"drawing">`, which completely loses the information we need to detect repeats.

---

Let's see if it works:

```
getGoogleApiUrl('', []); // okay
getGoogleApiUrl('', ['drawing']); // okay
getGoogleApiUrl('', ['drawing', 'geometry']); // okay
getGoogleApiUrl('', ['drawing', 'geometry', 'places', 'visualization']); // okay
getGoogleApiUrl('', ['foo']); // error!
//                   ~~~~~
// Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type 'AllMapLibraries'


getGoogleApiUrl('123', ['drawing', 'geometry', 'drawing']); // error!
//                      ~~~~~~~~~              ~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'
```

That all behaves more or less as expected.  The error message in the last case (like "`string` is not `undefined`") is not what you might hope to see in a perfect world.  If there were a supported [custom invalid type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689), we would use it to tailor the error message.  But there isn't.

At least the red squigglies are in meaningful locations.  Well, maybe you'd want only *one* of those to be an error; but that would make `RemoveArrayRepeats` even more complicated (e.g., only compare an element to elements at lower indices, but the compiler doesn't understand "lower indices" so we'd need some representation and it would get ugly quickly).

But this is about the closest I can get to your requirements without pages of code.  It's up to you whether even this version is worth it.  Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.7-Beta&ssl=24&ssc=23&pln=24&pc=26#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCAbDBZAhmAGQEsAjKXKI4AZzgF44ByAE3IHciA7Ac0bgB8m3YBAC2wGFER9BjMBlwBjGjKYA3ItQCuuDEQBeuGEQidGAbgCwAKBtIUcAErBRENcDRRyiZyiPUAHgAVOFAYYE5mWihgXGZTDEQ4XE5EAG0AXQA+ejgAbxs4Irg0gGk4LjgAa2BECAAzOCCMgC44AApC4u6gtM4tURJgKAzQkHDI2jySgAUKzmrahqbWuDmwiKi4coB+OE5gdyg4Nt6Z0YBfPoGhka7uor2Do-uH07KM14BKGwubO2QqCCNBgAGVcOJcs5XO5PN5fLEYIE0gBGAA0cAATBiAMwYgAsGIArNlzHAAPTkkrorG4gnEz7WexAkEAESI9UaDGhbg8XlwPmAfiRAVRGOxcDxtLgJKyZMp1Ixz2GdP2hxVMsZ-2szGAigUMTgilM1HgwhgAHEIBBuBgPGAiABVKAYNrBMYTLaYHD4YhkChUaiZLKdazdfBEUq1Nqmyg8NGvPT+yg0NrtEIAMicLl5cIFCP8wSyXwEJUZJboOVjXG4Vls1nNVptdrQDudGHajEYGMyX3lVIgVQFNkb1tt9qdLs73ZKLHYNcYGT7FIHQ8QI4kTfHrcnHa7PbnuA4PBnjGEYgkUkXy4Vg+HDc3Y5bban+9nrCPC4xZ5E4kk0m-eQlBUb8NG0XQDCMEwzCXfs4DvdcH0tJ8J3bacD3qa1rzg4YoGgABCGwFQeEjSIAPwoiiiKpIJASYAAiTCIHovhNH2CB4FwahqCIbhOFwEg7QQCAEDoxhvTwQhSHIFNqEYbUN2Q5tUNfFFMRxGc0kPY9eG-c8-yvb8Px07CV1CLwCOo0jrPIyi7LImyHnsuyrNohxGGrE8KloTgOOSbjeP4wTUBgETmSYLRImAeouGAZh5PrIA)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Set!

```
var uniques = new Set([0,1,1,2])
```

This results in:

```
Set(3) {0, 1, 2}
```

Then adding new elements like:

```
uniques.add(1)
```

Will also result in:

```
Set(3) {0, 1, 2}
```

Comment: yes set will do the job in runtime, but i would like to have already error in ts, before compilation

Comment: @JurajKocan It's *weird* to do the uniqueness check at compile time using the type system alone. It might be possible but then the definition would have to be recursive. And it will be odd what happens if you do `libraries.add("places")`. If you want to solve this using types, it seems to be more appropriate to use an object `{drawing: boolean, geometry: boolean, places: boolean, visualization: boolean}` which will *guarantee* you don't have duplicates. Otherwise, a Set or simply filtering duplicates in the function at runtime is what would normally be done.

Comment: @VLAZ the whole point of this is that i wanted to have nice code, there are solution like set or  object like u said or just name these 4 parameters in func. but i was looking for solution where i would just call this function like getGoogleApiUrl('apikey', ''lib1, lib2'') (or ['lib1', 'lib2', 'lib3'])

Comment: Then a "nice code solution" seems to be using an options object with the possible libraries as keys. It makes a lot more sense to me than sending an array of strings. It might be nice to validate `fn([1, 2])` and `fn([1, 2, 1])` but you can always pass an array variable, so what happens if you do `myArr = [1]; /* later */ myArr.push(2); /* later */ myarr.sort(sorter); /* later */ myArr.splice(1, 1); /* later */ fn(myArr.concat(otherVar))` - if this code needs to be type-safe. How would that work? Requires evaluating the operations as if at runtime but without the benefit of runtime data.

Comment: in fact i dont really care about runtime, if you do ['drawing', 'drawing', 'drawing'] and then send it to google api it will works anyway.so i am not even going to validate these values in runtime.even is you send request with no existing libraries. so all of this is just about to precompile time and "nice code", "easy to write"

Comment: so const librariesString = libraries.join(','); is everything i have to do now, if i would use object there would be much more code to take these libraries to string like this

Comment: `Object.entries(options).filter(([key, value]) => value).map(([key]) => key).join(",")` is not THAT much more. And `[...librariesSet].join(",")` is even less. I think it's wrong to leverage the type system just to save yourself typing several characters. It's better to focus on *correctness* of the implementeation not *least LOC*.

Comment: Object.entries(options) there you just loose typecheck. this is something you want to avoid in ts

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options if you need compile-time checking.

1. Use an Object which has in built duplication errors.

```js
type AllMapLibraries = 'drawing'|'geometry';
type AllMapLibraries_Obj = {[P in AllMapLibraries]:boolean};
const getGoogleApiUrl = (apiKey:string, librariesObj:AllMapLibraries_Obj) => {
    const libraries = Object.keys(librariesObj) as AllMapLibraries[];

    // alternatively you could do
    if ('geometry' in librariesObj) {}

    // ...
};

// This will error, you can't specify the same object property twice
const url = getGoogleApiUrl('123', { drawing: true, drawing: true });

// This will work
const url = getGoogleApiUrl('123', { geometry: true });
```

2. Use a Tuple which has index based constraints.

```js
type AllMapLibraries = Partial<['drawing', 'geometry']>;
const getGoogleApiUrl = (apiKey:string, libraries:AllMapLibraries) => {
    // ...
};

// This will error, you can't use 'drawing' in the index that 'geometry' goes
const url = getGoogleApiUrl('123', ['drawing', 'drawing']);

// This will work
const url = getGoogleApiUrl('123', [,'geometry']);
```

Drawbacks:

Objects can be more annoying to work with and may need a lot of rewriting.

Tuples are hard to use if you have a big array, as you may need many commas to get to the correct index. You also need to filter out `undefined`.