# Apply a complex generic type recursively

Tags: typescript, generics, null, mapped-types

Thanks to [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58409603/generate-a-type-where-each-nullable-value-becomes-optional) from Nit, I have a generic type `NullValuesToOptional` that generates types where each nullable value becomes optional:

```
type NullValuesToOptional<T> = Omit<T, NullableKeys<T>> & Partial<Pick<T, NullableKeys<T>>>;

type NullableKeys<T> = NonNullable<({
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends NonNull<T[K]> ? never : K
})[keyof T]>;

type NonNull<T> = T extends null ? never : T;
```

It works:

```
interface A {
  a: string
  b: string | null
}
type B = NullValuesToOptional<A>; // { a: string, b?: string | null }
```

Now I would like to make `NullValuesToOptional` recursive:

```
interface C {
  c: string
  d: A | null
  e: A[]
}
type D = NullValuesToOptional<C>;
// { c: string, d?: NullValuesToOptional<A> | null, e: NullValuesToOptional<A>[] }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Wow, I [*just mentioned* recursive type definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58411739/typescript-no-repeat-value#comment103166962_58411862) (albeit in a different context) which actually got me wondering if it's even possible to have any kind of recursive type. And then this question pops up. For what it's worth, it seems like it should be possible in theory, at least. Not sure if it's implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: included TS 3.7 version + array types

---

Do you mean something like this?

TS 3.7+ (generic type arguments in arrays can now be [circular](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33050)):

```
type RecNullValuesToOptional<T> = T extends Array<any>
  ? Array<RecNullValuesToOptional<T[number]>>
  : T extends object
  ? NullValuesToOptional<{ [K in keyof T]: RecNullValuesToOptional<T[K]> }>
  : T;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7-Beta&ssl=50&ssc=23&pln=41&pc=1#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-CqCxs4pPR3EAF70RmrEKBRwQcfx3EqLx9wMQAjnAmQiS03BSYpcDKapfQtJYpHkORABMlGuDRUB0YxeDMWJUDYr+nECTx3DyU5wmiT4ElBIErlKSpokOfxSnaRmunmFANYZJq3bcKgUBsFgWDXLIQA)

< TS 3.7 (a type resolution deferring [interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3496#issuecomment-128553540) is necessary):

```
type RecNullValuesToOptional<T> = T extends Array<any>
  ? RecNullValuesToOptionalArray<T[number]>
  : T extends object
  ? NullValuesToOptional<{ [K in keyof T]: RecNullValuesToOptional<T[K]> }>
  : T;

interface RecNullValuesToOptionalArray<T>
  extends Array<RecNullValuesToOptional<T>> {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgGwQNQIYLhAzgFQPYDyYwAlngHboA8OAfFALxQEC2JwNANLIgqgEYIIAaQggsNWvQBkAKChQACqgBOpaopIBjANZceSAUNHjJUgNyzZoSAb6CRYiXUawK8Qw6ryoACgDeUADawlAk5FA6YngAZlA4ALoAXPEhCVAQAB7AEOQAJlhu5B4INGn0APxQ5BAAbhAqUCmhAL4AlEFRILHxCbK0ltbg0DDuvJKuOBnZuQXVvFBVNfWNKTiD4TkqMaha0ACCUP4+qClYwCrhAOaWCvxnF9dQAD7zSJYtQ7YAQq4laBhsPgiKQKNR9gMoAB6KFHKCnKDnS7kK7cfgVB7Iq4vN4IKCfWSbBo7PZQADCRx8Wkx11uUDyKUOr3IvDpEEZQQSdJiKRZLH4DU5OJZ71kBJs0AAIn9eADMLhCMQyJRSmSBlYJVAAEoQLT-dDy4FKsGlFxMKZZHL5Qr7FQqVAgKiocggWg+Ko6vWyg1AxWglW2+2OnBBPkClQJN0KNbTK1zPD8ABWuuA7rsct9IOV1ECITCES6PUSKU9+sBCqzJrKwkj+KjTXidMJ5C2JOgpe95aN-vQgYdkh8ltmNrt-Y7SAzFeNKrMR3FwygAFFXOOUD6pz3VerZDCoMAABYkQpHqCJuDnKAxPCNEhIc8XVD+qBgOAqMB4LDQYB4KAC4BbRF9zwAB3Pd9y-BdwjA6AAElJUXL5oAAMT4f9cgmc1Y2HKAE2TLRUwUKoLRma18xiBpmB8Qi4TzKDCziAhkigFDHytKgCHKfEqIbZYGh8NZLE1RckOvFhWIgPJXBYtDyCoRdty0CgL3ZJdXGOBRqSgAAiK88C0zgfAZOEES0-hVH038UlM1AAC8tPxAyFBUoJAhMsyVAs+5tIARzgTJ7JabhXKs3y-ICvoWksRTyGUgAmFJlyYdSoE0nS8D0xz6RSYLtPczyrLMuyHMHFIXMsnywoc4yQrgSqWgi8xoVhBoVGvbhUCgNgsCwa5ZCAA)

Test the type:

```
interface A {
  a: string;
  b: string | null;
}

interface C {
  c: string;
  d: A | null;
  e: A[];
  f: number[] | null;
}

/*
type EFormatted  = {
    c: string;
    e: {
        a: string;
        b?: string | null | undefined;
    }[];
    d?: {
        a: string;
        b?: string | null | undefined;
    } | null | undefined;
    f?: number[] | null | undefined;
}

=> type EFormatted is the "flattened" version of 
type E and used for illustration purposes here;
both types E and EFormatted are equivalent, see also Playground
*/
type E = RecNullValuesToOptional<C>
```

Test with some data:

```
const e: E = {
  c: "foo",
  d: { a: "bar", b: "baz" },
  e: [{ a: "bar", b: "qux" }, { a: "quux" }]
};
const e2: E = {
  c: "foo",
  d: { a: "bar", b: "baz" },
  e: [{ b: "qux" }, { a: "quux" }]
}; // error, a missing (jep, that's OK)
```

Comment: Thank you for l'update with arrays. Very interesting.